# how to convert varchar(50) datatype of column into datetime?

Tags: c#

I have to retrive data in `gridview` from two date. I have two `textbox` first is `txtFromDate` and second is `txtTodate`. In my table `DateTime` is stored as `Varchar datatype` thus when i am selecting `FromDate "1/7/2016" and ToDate "18/7/2017"` its also showing last month data i.e. `6th month (June) data`. I do not want it. Therefore i want to convert `varchar` datatype into `Datetime` using following query.

```
Select * from Vtable 
where convert(datetime,InDateTime,105) between '"+txtFromDate+"' and '"+txtToDate+"';
```

But this giving error out-of-range. Plz help me to solve this error.

Comment: First, **fix** your database. It's using the wrong data type. Don't just cover that up by trying to change the data type when *querying* the data.

Comment: The type conversion should happen on C# side, not SQL side. With either `Convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` you can get valid date format to attach them on SQL statement, thus eliminating out-of-range problem.

Comment: I not want to change datatype of column. I just want to convert it so that it should display data between two selected date..